# How to interact with a spawned process and capture its output in ruby?

Tags: ruby, spawn, pry

I have a ruby program that runs rake tasks for me and captures the output.  Right now they're being run inside PTY.spawn.  I'm experiencing two problems with this approach:

1. I can't use binding.pry inside the child process.
2. Processes that rewrite their own output (such as the progress bar gem) produce output, but can't delete previous output so I get a pile of progressive output where one line was expected.

I need to solve the pry issue.  It'd be nice if I could make the second issue go away in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Pry supports debugging remote processes, which should apply to a child process. Search for "pry-remote".

As far as deleting previous output, you don't seem to understand what really happens; You have to think in terms of how a TTY worked. The previous output isn't deleted, instead the cursor is moved to the start of the line using a carriage-return, not a new-line.

You can capture the output and use `lines`, which maintains the line separator, to break it into an array and take the first or last line. For instance:

```
text = "this is the first line."
text += "\rthis is another line."
text += "\rthis is the last line."
text # => "this is the first line.\rthis is another line.\rthis is the last line."

text.lines("\r").first # => "this is the first line.\r"
text.lines("\r").last # => "this is the last line."
```

Alternately you can use `split`, which *doesn't* return the line separator:

```
text.split("\r").first # => "this is the first line."
text.split("\r").last # => "this is the last line."
```

Comment: 1. Not interested in pry-remote.  It's a viable workaround, but I'd rather solve it directly.
2. The progress bar gem prints a line of progress.  Then when that changes it updates that line.  When I run it in an interactive terminal, the line is edited and replaced.  When I run it in PTY.spawn, the lines accumulate.  I understand what it's doing, I'm just not sure how to spawn another process that works like an interactive one.

Comment: Define "directly". You're going to have to fool the code if you want it to think it's started at the command-line when it was spawned by changing its environment so it thinks it was started by a TTY. But I suspect that'll lead right down a path full of dragons as you'll also be trying to fool Ruby. The separation of how a terminal displays strings vs. how the code generates them is important to understand; It sounds like you're trying to interact with the terminal's visual representation of the information, not with the code's generated output.